# Why does the & operator only work in variables and not in inline statements

Tags: c

```
printf("%i\n",2&2==2);
```

This should print out a 1 but I get a 0, why is this?

```
int ans=2&2;
printf("%i\n",ans==2);
```

This prints a 1, how come the first way does not work?
This is the case with if statements as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of operations is different than you think it is. A correct way to write it in a single line would be:

```
printf("%i\n", (2 & 2) == 2); // Prints 1
```

Comment: @BackSpace7777777: if you're not familiar with "operator precedence", see here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators_precedence.htm

Comment: @BackSpace7777777: `&` and `&&` used to be one context-sensitive operator. The weird precedence of `&` is an artifact of that history.